VUE 3 & Quasar QSlideItem component, @left : (details) => void
I am using Quasar's QSlideIten (q-slide-item) and the @left & @right event.
        <q-slide-item
          v-for="(tournament, index) in tournamentsFiltered()"
          :key="tournament.id"
          clickable
          v-ripple
          left-color="blue-5"
          right-color="red-5"
          @left="editTournament"
          @right="deleteTournament(tournament)"
          bordered
          :class="{ 'top-border' : index == 0,
          'bottom-border' : index == tournamentsFiltered().length - 1 }"
          >

In this example, the left event kicks off editTournament with no ().
  const editTournament = ({reset}) => {
    console.log('Edit tournament: ')
    reset()
  }

In my function, editTournaments I then have access to a method, reset() that is received from q-slide-item.
In my second function, deleteTournaments I need access to index or tournament details and sends tournament as an argument.
  const deleteTournament = (tournament) => {
    console.log('Delete tournament:', tournament)
    // How do I access reset() -OR- is my approach wrong
  }

The problem is when I call either of those functions with a trail () to the call, the reset() method is not available in my functions.
Can anyone guide me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Figured it out.
Changed the @right="deleteTournament(tournament, $event.reset)" and then reset() is available in deleteTournament function and confirmed worked as expected.
I guess I've learned something new, you can pass methods like $event.<method> as an argument...

Further proof of Quasar's ubiquity...
